# How to fill and access to std::map<std::pair<enum1, enum2>, funcPtr>?

Tags: c++, dictionary, enums, function-pointers, std-pair

I would like to know how to fill this type of map and mainly the way to access to the function pointer.

The map :

```
enum enum1
{
   val11,
   val12,
   val13
};

enum enum2
{
   val21,
   val22,
   val23
};

typedef void(MyClass::*funcPtr)();

std::map<std::pair<enum1, enum2>, funcPtr> map;
```

I fill it like this, it seems to work:

```
map.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(val11, val21), &MyClass::init));
```

But I can't access to the function like this:

```
map[std::make_pair<val11, val21>]();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong parentheses with `make_pair` and need to call the member function on some instance of `MyClass` (using the `.*` or `->*` operators):

```
MyClass obj;
(obj.*map[std::make_pair(val11, val21)])();
```

Comment: I'm trying : `this->*(map[std::make_pair(val11, val21)])();` it throw me an error : `error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in [...]`

Comment: It's just a precedence issue. Try: `(this->*map[std::make_pair(val11, val21)])();`

Comment: Yep, my mistake, forgot the first parenthesis. ^^